# How can I determine the device's current speed?

Tags: android, gps

I want to get the current speed of an Android device. I see the GPS location class provides the property, but I'm not sure whether it is available. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I have not got my Android device yet... I just use simulator , but no gps data can be use.....

Comment: You can feed dummy gps coordinates to the emulator in the "Emulator Control" view in Eclipse.  Try feeding it multiple sets of coordinates and see if it can determine the speed after the second set.

Comment: I wish I had enough reputation to edit, good question just needs to be fixed up a little. Erich put your comment as an answer and I'll up vote it.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood well your question, you are on the emulator and you want to try your application, if it handles well some speed measurements. You can test it, by passing "virtual" locations to the emulator. More info can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html#MockData)