# How can I find a user's walking speed using GPS?

Tags: android, gps

I want to find the walking speed of a person using GPS. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I determine the device's current speed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845990/how-can-i-determine-the-devices-current-speed)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for  a way to code that in an android app, or just an app that will do that for you?

Ican't help with code, but if it's the second one, here's a [link](http://www.android.com/market/#app=com.fitnesskeeper.runkeeper) to one. There are dozens, though. Look through the health section of the Android market. Any run timer or cyclometer will generally do.

Be aware that android is less consistently compatible with user generated apps, that some other ap markets, so make sure that whatever you use will work with your device befre you download it.

Comment: thanx for the reply , i am looking for some sample codes or any suggestions like how to achieve this task..